# Get an object is value is true angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get the object if it is featured as true. I am using a JSON database. I am getting no errors.
I ma really new to angular

This is my ts file

```
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

      cabin: Cabin;
      cabinErrMess: string;

      constructor(
        private cabinService: CabinService,
        @Inject('BaseURL') private BaseURL) {
        }



      ngOnInit() {
        this.getFeaturedCabin();
      }

      getFeaturedCabin(): void {
        this.cabinService.getFeaturedCabin()
        .subscribe(cabin => this.cabin = cabin);
      }


    }
```

this is my html

```
    <div  *ngIf="cabin" >   
        <img src ="{{cabin.image}}">
        <header><h1>{{cabin.name}}</h1></header>
        <p>{{cabin.description}}</p>
    </div>
```

this is my service

```
      getFeaturedCabin (): Observable<Cabin> {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3000/cabins?featured=true';
        return this.http.get<Cabin>(url).pipe(
          tap(_ => this.log('o')),
          catchError(this.handleError<Cabin>(`getFeaturedCabin`))
        );
      }
```

this is the JSON database it is extracting the information from.

```
              "cabins": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "description": "Tucked away on the hillside among lush gardens of banana & citrus trees",
          "featured": "true",
                    },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "description": "Perched on the mountain side overlooking the river valley, this hand crafted wooden cabin has great panoramic views.",
          "featured": "false",
          },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "description": "Perched below the Eagles Lair, these two hand crafted wooden Cabins have spectacular views.",
          "featured": "false",

        }
      ]
```

Comment: What is the expected return value from your service call? Are you receiving an error from your Angular code? your service backend? If so, what's the error? What does the service method look like? Right now, no one has any way to help you diagnose what might be the issue.

Comment: I added the database I am trying to extract the information from. I get no errors that makes it harder for me to realize what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service endpoint is returning an array of objects, but you're trying to assign a single "Cabin". You'll either need to adjust your service and component to allow for an array, or update your service endpoint to only return a single object.

If you update your service:

```
getFeaturedCabin (): Observable<Cabin> {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/cabins?featured=true';
    return this.http.get<Cabin>(url).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log('o')),
      catchError(this.handleError<Cabin>(`getFeaturedCabin`))
    );
  }
```

needs to be:

```
getFeaturedCabin (): Observable<Cabin[]> {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/cabins?featured=true';
    return this.http.get<Cabin>(url).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log('o')),
      catchError(this.handleError<Cabin>(`getFeaturedCabin`))
    );
  }
```

and your component needs to allow for "cabin**s**"

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  cabins: Cabin[];
  ...
}
```

Finally, update your template to allow for an array of cabins:

```
<div *ngFor="let cabin of cabins">   
    <img src ="{{cabin.image}}">
    <header><h1>{{cabin.name}}</h1></header>
    <p>{{cabin.description}}</p>
</div>
```

If you chose to update your service endpoint, make sure it's only returning a single object, for example:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "description": "Tucked away on the hillside among lush gardens of banana & citrus trees",
  "featured": "true",
}
```

If you need to do any comparisons on the "featured" key, notice the value isn't a boolean, it's a string, so you will need to do: `if (cabin.featured === 'true') { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the data structure correctly, as your backend is returning an object array with `cabins` for key, if you have a lot of featured cabins you can show them in your front end with an `*ngFor` directive. You will also need to set the cabins array in your frontend accordingly, so here's what you can do:

In your component, get the list of the cabins and save it in the cabins attribute:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  cabins: Cabin[];
  cabinErrMess: string;

  constructor(
    private cabinService: CabinService,
    @Inject('BaseURL') private BaseURL) {
    }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFeaturedCabin();
  }

  getFeaturedCabin(): void {
    this.cabinService.getFeaturedCabin()
    .subscribe(response => this.cabins = <Cabin[]> response.cabins);
  }


}
```

Then, in your template, use the `ngFor`directive to loop through your cabins array:

```
<div  *ngIf="cabins" *ngFor="let cabin of cabins" >   
    <img src ="{{cabin.image}}">
    <header><h1>{{cabin.name}}</h1></header>
    <p>{{cabin.description}}</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT: you will also need to update the service return type as noticed by the other answer.**

Enjoy !